# What does “bc same” mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english, idiom-meaning

What does “bc same” mean after a question?

Sth like:
Have you ever done that? Bc same.

Thanks

Comment: The full context would be very helpful.

Comment: 'bc' is sometimes used as an abbreviation for 'because'.  So 'bc same' might mean 'because same', itself perhaps meaning 'for the same reasons as before'... But without context this is all wild speculation.

Answer (score 1):

[Same](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=same) is mainly slang for "me too/I feel the same". @Jermey was right about bc, it's an abbreviation for because.

In this instance, I believe it's mostly a rhetorical question asked to a friend when you already know their answer. Alternatively, you could just saying that you don't really care, that you're agreeing with whatever your friend says/decides.

For example: Do you want a lake house? Bc same. | Would you tap that? Bc same. | Do you want to go? Bc same.

Usually it's just statements in this form though: A: I'm so hungry. B: Same.

Answer (score 1):

There are three new things going on here, 'bc' and 'same'.

- 'bc' is a textspeak abbreviation for 'because'.
- 'same' is a textspeak abbreviation of 'same here' or 'The same situation holds for me too'. An example of dialog:

  > A: "I am hungry."
  >
  > B: "Same."

  meaning the second person is stating that they are hungry too.
- 'because X' is a new slang pattern of speaking. Normally 'because' takes a full sentence. This new pattern treats it as a preposition and X as a noun phrase (even if it is not). It could be transformed into the usual pattern by saying 'because of X' or 'because X is the case'. For example:

  > A: Why do politicians make laws supporting corporations instead of individuals?
  >
  > B: Because money.

  meaning that politicians do somethings for their own personal money rather than the right thing.

  'Because of X' is the idiomatic way, but 'because X' is a new slang way of saying (or more likely, writing it).